# Разрешить DELETE только без pk Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Требуется разрешить посылать запросы:

```
DELETE /users (в body находятся ids для удаления)
```

Но запретить:

```
DELETE /users/{id}
```

Мой алгоритм:

1. Создал обычный класс `UserViewSet`, который наследуется от `DestroyModelMixin` и `GenericViewSet`.
2. Реализовал метод `def delete(self, request)`, теперь запрос `DELETE /users` выполняется корректно.

Проблема в том, что нужно еще запретить посылать запрос вида `DELETE /users/{id}`.

Пытался перестать наследоваться от `DestroyModelMixin`, но тогда выдается страница `404 Not Found`, так как отсутствует машрут.

Пытался реализовать метод `delete` с такой сигнатурой:

```
def delete(self, request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        return Response(data='PK is not allowed in DELETE method')
```

Но, видимо для `DELETE /users/{id}` всегда используется метод `def destroy(self, request, pk)`.

Единственное, как у меня получилось сделать - это вот так:

```
def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    raise exceptions.MethodNotAllowed('DELETE with PK')
```

При запросе `DELETE /users/{id}` выдается, что метод `DELETE with PK` не разрешен.

Но я так понимаю - это совсем странное решение и можно сделать как-то намного проще. Буду благодарен за подсказку.

Также в `urls.py` используются `SimpleRouter` маршруты, не особо понимаю нужно ли в данном случае от них уходить.

Comment: а почему бы без танцев с бубном не написать самую обычную [функцию](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view)?

Comment: Думаю, можно было в `urls.py` через регулярки указать, что метод `/users` только в таком виде: `^/users$`. Смотрите в функцию `re_path`

Comment: @Dmitry не могу понять, как в данном случае это можно использовать, чтобы разрешить один запрос и запретить другой( поясните, пожалуйста

Comment: @gil9red если сделать так, то оно ведь тоже будет выдавать ошибку 404, а не `DELETE not allowed?`

Comment: @Dmitry но у меня ведь так и есть, сделан viewset, в нем определен delete (правда, без декоратора, но и без него `DELETE /users` отрабатывает),  но как это запрещает посылать `DELETE /users/{id}`?

Comment: хотя прошу прощения, я ввел вас в заблуждение. декоратор не принимает путь.